# Create multiple columns from a single column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working on a data frame that has a column with the following:

```
         Products
1           A;B
2           A
3           D;A;C
```

I would like to have instead:

```
          Has_A      Has_B        Has_C   ...
1           1          1            0
2           1          0            0
```

Also, as a step further, there are some rows that contains something like "No products"   or "None" and there is NaNs, I would like to put all these into 1 column (if possible ).

Any tips ? Is it possible to do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) mainly:

```
df = df['Products'].str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix('Has_')
print (df)
   Has_A  Has_B  Has_C  Has_D
0      1      1      0      0
1      1      0      0      0
2      1      0      1      1
```

Sample:

There is also add solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict` created with `list comprehension` and added `NaN` and `None`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Products': ['A;B', 'A', 'D;A;C', 'No prods', np.nan, 'None']})
print (df)
   Products
0       A;B
1         A
2     D;A;C
3  No prods
4       NaN
5      None

L = ['No prods','None']
d = {x :'No product' for x in L + [None, np.nan]}
df['Products'] = df['Products'].replace(d)
df = df['Products'].str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix('Has_')
print (df)
   Has_A  Has_B  Has_C  Has_D  Has_No product
0      1      1      0      0               0
1      1      0      0      0               0
2      1      0      1      1               0
3      0      0      0      0               1
4      0      0      0      0               1
5      0      0      0      0               1
```

Comment: Thank you Jez it worked ! simple question: can you explain the code for the variable d ? (i know its the one that answers the second part of mu question )

Comment: It is dictionary comprehension which create new duct by values from list `L` for replace another data.

Comment: I found that I'm losing the other columns, is there a way to conserve the other columns than "Products" ? df['Products'] = df['Products'].str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix('Has_') didn't work

Comment: I think you can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) - `df = df_orig.join(df)`

Comment: Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)  - `df = pd.concat([df_orig, df], axis=1)`

Comment: and with removing old column `df = pd.concat([df_orig.drop('Products', axis=1), df], axis=1)`