# Adding missing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, encoding

This question is the continuation of [Create multiple columns from a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653398/).
Supposing now we have 2 dataframes, train and test, how can I be able to add missing columns for each ?
Regards,

EDIT:
train dataframe:

```
         Products
1           A;B
2           A
3           B;A;C
```

Became:

```
          Has_A      Has_B        Has_C   
1           1          1            0
2           1          0            0
3           1          1            1
```

Test dataframe:

```
         Products
1           A;B
2           A
3           D;A;B
```

Became:

```
          Has_A      Has_B      Has_D
1           1          1          0
2           1          0          0
3           1          1          1
```

train has "Has_C" and test has "Has_D" in plus each.

I would like to add the Has_C column to the test and the Has_D to the train filling them with 0.

Comment: Do it twice....

Comment: Some values are not present in both sets

Comment: Can you explain more? Some sample data are the best.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.assign()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method:

```
all_cols = train.columns.union(test.columns)

train = train.assign(**{col:0 for col in all_cols.difference(train.columns).tolist()})
test = test.assign(**{col:0 for col in all_cols.difference(test.columns).tolist()})
```

Demo:

```
In [310]: train.assign(**{col:0 for col in all_cols.difference(train.columns).tolist()})
Out[310]:
   Has_A  Has_B  Has_C  Has_D
1      1      1      0      0
2      1      0      0      0
3      1      1      1      0

In [311]: test.assign(**{col:0 for col in all_cols.difference(test.columns).tolist()})
Out[311]:
   Has_A  Has_B  Has_D  Has_C
1      1      1      0      0
2      1      0      0      0
3      1      1      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of `columns`:

```
train = train['Products'].str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix('Has_')
test = test['Products'].str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix('Has_')

cols = train.columns.union(test.columns)
print (cols)
Index(['Has_A', 'Has_B', 'Has_C', 'Has_D'], dtype='object')

train = train.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (train)
   Has_A  Has_B  Has_C  Has_D
1      1      1      0      0
2      1      0      0      0
3      1      1      1      0

test = test.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0)
print (test)
   Has_A  Has_B  Has_C  Has_D
1      1      1      0      0
2      1      0      0      0
3      1      1      0      1
```

Comment: It's a very good idea to use `.reindex_axis(...)` - i like it

Answer (score 0):

// fetch columns not in train_df

cols = list(set(train_df.columns.values) - set(test_df.columns.values))

// create dummy dataframe and join with train_df

pd.DataFrame([[0 for col in cols]],columns=cols).join(test_df,how='outer').fillna(0)

Do same process for train_df

Hope it helps :)